# Avoid std::shared_mutex from writer thread, when it needs to read

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, c++17, std

Assume I have a scenario with three threads:

- TW: a thread which writes some shared data and occasionally reads the same data as well;
- TR1: a thread which accesses the data only for reading;
- TR2: a thread which accesses the data only for reading;

The threads use a`std::shared_mutex`.
When TW needs to write the data, it acquires a `std::unique_lock`; whereas when TR1 or TR2 need to read the data, they acquire a `std::shared_lock` on the mutex.

Now my question: when TW needs to read the shared data, does it necessarily have to acquire a `std::shared_lock` as well ?

Could it simply access the data without any lock, given only itself can modify the data ?

Comment: Even if it's possible to prove that TW is a special case, I think it's better to keep the lock paradigm consistent. "Reading the shared data requires a shared lock on the data mutex" is a simple policy that scales to, say, creating TW2. The costs of acquiring a shared lock in TW should be very low if there's no contention anyway.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with ultra-low-latency scenarios, where even a minuscule delay is unacceptable, you should go for consistency and just access the data from TW while holding the read lock - this will solve you so many headaches if you ever will need to change threading distribution. Although you are correct, this is not technically necessary.

Comment: Just to be clear, if TW already holds a `unique_lock`, it should not additionally acquire a `shared_lock` to read.

Comment: yes of course I am assuming TW doesn't hold a `unique_lock` already.  
I totally agree with the consistency argument. Was just curious to know whether this scenario would result in something like undefined behavior or it is allowed by the standard.